# How to wrap async callback with Observable or async/await?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I am using a network API which works with callbacks. So basically, I have a bunch of method calls that I need to use in this 3rd party library which look like this:

```
void SendNetworkRequest(string requestType, Action<Response> callback)
```

I find the code getting a little bit wacky because all of my methods which depend on network resources from this 3rd party API also need to implement callbacks themselves. For example, in my main scene I may want to get the players information and my code would look something like this:

```
void InitMainScene()
{
       _networkHelper.SendNetworkRequest("GetPlayersInfo",OnPlayerInfoResponse);
}

void OnPlayerInfoResponse(Response response)
{
     _playerInfo = response.Info;
}
```

I have recently gotten into RX and am using it abundently in my code. I have read read some about async/await. I have experimented quite a bit, especially with RX, and tried working with Observable.FromAsync() but could not get it to work..

What am I missing here? How can I write code which is cleaner and doesn't require the callback using RX or async/await? The following is the psuedocode which I'm looking for:

```
        void InitMainScene()
        {
            _playerInfo = Overservable.DoMagicThing<Response>( () => {
_networkHelper.SendNetworkRequest("GetPlayersInfo",(r) =>{return r;}); });
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about RX. However, you can convert callback-based SendNetworkRequest to an awaitable task like this:

```
void SendNetworkRequest(string requestType, Action<Response> callback)
        {
            // This code by third party, this is here just for testing
            if (callback != null)
            { 
                var result = new Response();
                callback(result);
            }
        }

        Task<Response> SendNetworkRequestAsync(string requestType)
        {
            return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var t = new TaskCompletionSource<Response>();

                SendNetworkRequest(requestType, s => t.TrySetResult(s));

                return t.Task;
            });
        }
```

Now you can consume SendNetworkRequestAsync with async/await more naturally

Comment: Thank you so much! this is GREAT! I will play with this today. Question for you - do you recommend this semantic over the Overservable in my case? BTW - I have not yet used async/await, and in fact, I'm doing this in Unity3d which only supports .net 4.6 as an experimental feature.

Comment: RX is great if you are handling a stream of events. In your case, you call SendNetworkRequest then wait for the task complete, that's it. So yes, async/await is easier and more reasonable than Rx in this case. Clean and easier

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to do it with Rx. I swapped out `Response` for `string` just so I could compile and test, but trivial to swap back.:

```
public IObservable<string> SendNetworkRequestObservable(string requestType)
{
    return Observable.Create<string>(observer =>  
    {
        SendNetworkRequest(requestType, s => observer.OnNext(s));
        observer.OnCompleted();
        return Disposable.Empty;
    });
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public void SendNetworkRequest(string requestType, Action<string> callback)
{
    callback(requestType); // implementation for testing purposes
}
```

Comment: Urrgh - If you're ever returning `Disposable.Empty` then you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: thanks @Schlomo! This helps me a lot! I will play with this and try to understand better the implications of Disposable.Empty which Enigmativity describes

Comment: @Enigmativity, feel free to expand why. I disagree: In this case there's nothing to dispose, but a subscription requires a disposable. This is a perfect example for why `Disposable.Empty` exists.

Comment: @Shlomo - I look at `Disposable.Empty` a bit like `catch (Exception ex)` - it's a bit of an anti-pattern. It's often easy just to do a few `.OnNext` calls and return `Disposable.Empty` - which always leads to a synchronous subscription call. I take it as good practice to try to find a way to avoid using `Disposable.Empty`. You're right that this might be a perfect example as to why it exists though.

Comment: @Shlomo - I look at `Disposable.Empty` a bit like `catch (Exception ex)` - it's a bit of an anti-pattern. It's often easy just to do a few `.OnNext` calls and return `Disposable.Empty` - which always leads to a synchronous subscription call. I take it as good practice to try to find a way to avoid using `Disposable.Empty`. You're right that this might be a perfect example as to why it exists though.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on doing this with Rx.

Inside the `NetworkHelper` class add this method:

```
public IObservable<Response> SendNetworkRequestObservable(string requestType)
{
    return
        Observable
            .Create<Response>(observer =>
            {
                Action<Response> callback = null;
                var callbackQuery =
                    Observable
                        .FromEvent<Response>(h => callback += h, h => callback -= h)
                        .Take(1);
                var subscription = callbackQuery.Subscribe(observer);
                this.SendNetworkRequest(requestType, callback);
                return subscription;
            });
}
```

This creates an observable that internally uses `Observable.FromEvent(...).Take(1)` to create an observable based on expecting a single call to the `Action<Response> callback` passed to the `SendNetworkRequest` method.

The only issue with this is that the call occurs on the current thread right to completion. If you want this code to run on a background thread, but return the result to the current thread, then you can do this:

```
public IObservable<Response> SendNetworkRequestObservable(string requestType)
{
    return
        Observable
            .Start(() =>
                Observable
                    .Create<Response>(observer =>
                    {
                        Action<Response> callback = null;
                        var callbackQuery =
                            Observable
                                .FromEvent<Response>(h => callback += h, h => callback -= h)
                                .Take(1);
                        var subscription = callbackQuery.Subscribe(observer);
                        this.SendNetworkRequest(requestType, callback);
                        return subscription;
                    }))
            .Merge();
}
```

Either way you'd call it like this:

```
var _playerInfo =
    _networkHelper
        .SendNetworkRequestObservable("GetPlayersInfo")
        .Wait();
```

Just a side-note: your `DoMagicThing` is a synchronous call. In Rx that's a `.Wait()` call, but it's better to just use a normal `.Subscribe` when you can.

---

As per the comment, you could do this with `async`:

```
async void InitMainScene()
{
    _playerInfo = await _networkHelper.SendNetworkRequestObservable("GetPlayersInfo");
}
```

Comment: Thank you SO much for this example. I've been spending some time trying to get it to work in my game.. it seems though that the .Wait() method is causing Unity to freeze and then crash. I need to get digging as to why - even async/await example below does the same. Thanks SO much for the help! I wanted to ask you - do you think async/await is a better solution to this problem, or do you think your solution is cleaner for this specific case? It's hard to know which one to use in which situation as I'm so inexperienced with both right now. Thanks again!

Comment: @user3010678 - What you shouldn't be doing is using `.Wait()`. You should use a regular .Subscribe(...)` call or, better yet, use `async` and make the call look like this: `var _playerInfo = await _networkHelper.SendNetworkRequestObservable("GetPlayersInfo");`. That works with observables and returns the last value produced (if more than one are).